# Any difference in "paradise lost" and "lost paradise"?

Tags: word-order

Imagine a book named:

"paradise lost" and another named "lost paradise"? would them imply any differences in meaning?

the reason I'm asking is to get a better understand in adjective positional rules and how it affects the meaning of sentences

Comment: I have asked a similar question around a year ago which was 'required qualifications vs qualifications required'. In 'Lost paradise' the meaning is that something is already lost and in 'Paradise Lost' the emphasis is laid on 'lost'. Another thing I Just wanna add is that often Participle clauses are post-modifiers. I haven't posted it as an answer as I too have some doubts.

Answer (score 2):

It's complicated a bit because neither of the two-word phrases is a full sentence. In this case, no, we can change the order and the meaning isn't really affected (well—not *really* really. More in a second). Almost 300 years after *Paradise Lost*, a book was written called *Lost Horizon*.

I say that the meaning doesn't "*really* really" change, but there is a slight difference. This might be open to argument, but I would say the "lost" in *Lost Horizon* is an adjective, as if it were "Red Horizon" or "Dim Horizon." But Milton's sequel to *Paradise Lost* is *Paradise Regained*. He's using "lost" as a participle, meaning "a paradise *that someone **has** lost*." Similar constructions would be "Paradise Forgotten" or "Paradise Discovered."

If we were talking about full sentences, generally English would simply put simple modifiers before the noun. Shifting them after it does not significantly change meaning, though it can make the tone lofty or archaic. It is probably out of place in modern writing, unless for poetic effect:

> He regaled them with tales of days past.
> They built a tower high and broad.

BUT if the modifier is not just one word but a phrase, it is much easier to make it follow the noun:

> He built a house taller than any other in town.
> It was a secret known only to the wisest.

Comment: You could say, perhaps, that *Paradise Lost* refers to a paradise which some **person** has lost (active voice, emphasis on the person) and *Lost Paradise* refers to a paradise which **has been** lost (passive voice). Would you agree?

Comment: @randomhead I think I agree with your general point, if perhaps I'm confused by the specifics—this is why I hedged my bet with "this might be open to argument." (When is "lost" an adjective and when is it a participle?) Adding to the confusion, *lost* can also be intransitive ("I'm lost!"). But yes, I agree that Milton's title puts more emphasis on the unstated "loser" than Hilton's (omg, they rhyme!). It's arguably even a different meaning: "We have lost [access to] Paradise" vs "We have lost [track of, awareness of] the horizon."

Comment: @randomhead I agree and I think that is why _Paradise Lost_ is much more stylistically pleasing to me.